# What is purpose to use async action if we have in action single operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is purpose of using an async action if we have in action single operation? This operation is long running but it is still one operation. I often see in articles (for example in article:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CreatingAsynchGizmos) the code like below:

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        int result = await Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(LongRunningOperation);

        ViewBag.Result = result;

        return View();
    }

    private int LongRunningOperation()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50000);
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I understand the purpose if we have in action two and more long running operations but if we have one operation? The async action runs the same time like sync action if we have in action one operation.

Comment: Doing a new thread like that is almost never a good idea in asp.net, you get 0 benefit and it makes your website slower.

Comment: @user3691221: The code in the article you referenced is not *at all* the same as the code you posted in this question. In particular, the question's code uses `StartNew`, a very bad idea to start with, and *especially* bad on ASP.NET for reasons Scott Chamberlain pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

The `await` expression doesn't block like a synchronous call would. It forces the compiler to do a continuation on the awaited task at a later point (when the task is done, it resumes where it left off).

Even if you have just one operation, it can free up the calling thread to do something else. This would be more obvious in a `WinForms` or `WPF` application where the calling thread is a UI thread, causing your screen to freeze if you do not have `await`.

In the case of WebAPI, you're freeing up IIS' thread pool to handle requests and do additional processing.

Comment: But in that case my website freezes in sync and async action.

Comment: The website is not "freezing" it is just waiting for the method to complete before the result is returned. If you want a "early result" async is not the solution to that problem.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I know but I still don't understand when to use async action if I have ONLY ONE long running operation.

Comment: It depends on what that one long running operation is. If it is a database request you should use the async API of the database request and await on that, if it is CPU heavy code and you only have one of them you should NOT use async and just run the cpu heavy code like normal.

Comment: Just to add to @ScottChamberlain's point. Don't think in terms of how long something takes when choosing to use async or not. Instead, think in terms of how much *waiting* the thread will be doing. If you were to make a request to a web service for example, there's network latency in send the request (thread is waiting), time for the destination server to respond (thread is waiting) and more network latency receiving the response (thread is waiting). That's a prime candidate for async.

Comment: But, if you're doing complex financial analysis that's burning up the CPU and takes a long time, async does nothing. The thread can't be released because it's actively being used - it's not *waiting*. In that case, using async just adds additional overhead with no benefit. It's not about how long something takes, it's about how much time the thread is idle.

Comment: So for example: I send in action request to database to get data (application thread isn't free), database gathers data (application thread is free and can do something else), application gets data (thread isn't free)

Comment: Exactly, however when you make the database request you need to make sure you use the methods that return a `Task` or `Task<T>` and await on those methods. For example if you are using EntityFramework doing `List<YourTable> result = await db.YourTable.Where(x= x.Foo == "Bar").ToListAsync();` instead of `List<YourTable> result = db.YourTable.Where(x= x.Foo == "Bar").ToList();`

Comment: Thx Scott and the others :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you have a finite number of worker threads for ASP.NET requests.  Even if your request has only one long running operation, typically that operation is IO bound (e.g. a network or database operation).  You can therefore use an asynchronous action to free up the ASP.NET worker thread to service other requests while awaiting the result of your operation.

The benefit is less clear in your example, because your long running operation will end up freeing the ASP.NET worker thread only to resume on a different worker thread.